# Sharepoint 2019 OnPremise and Active Directory Federation Services SecurityTokenResolver key error

Tags: sharepoint, adfs

I'm becoming mad trying to set up ADFS authentication for Sharepoint. The error I'm getting is:

Ensure that the SecurityTokenResolver is populated with the required key

The error is thrown by /_trust/default.aspx that is the endpoint where ADFS redirects after successful login and clearly states that the certificate I've used to create New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer and also imported as SPTrustedRootAuthority for the whole Sharepoint is not trusted by the certificate used by ADFS for Token-Signing and Token-Decrypting mechanism.

I've tried with my own certificates from a CA enroled to AD and with a commercial one. I've verified that thumbrints correspond in both sides, SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer/SPTrustedRootAuthority and ADFS side.

Need some help here before going completely crazy.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.

The certificate must be exported from ADFS Token-Signing one. This is the one you want to use for the client side. In this case Sharepoint SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your information. You can mark this answer if this issue has been resolved. It will be helpful to those who have the same issues with yours.